# Exception in thread main java.lang.classnotfoundexception

Tags: java, maven

При запуске `jar` файла появляется

> Exception in thread main java.lang.classnotfoundexception:
>   javax\servlet\Servlet

Проект собирал `maven`'ом , вот содержимое `pom.xml`

```
<groupId>L2.1</groupId>
<artifactId>L2.1</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поменял билд на данный и все заработало

```
     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить `scope`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Не помогло. В импортированных библиотеках javax.servlet присутствует, зависимость тоже объявлена. По каким причинам он может не находить данный класс ? чтоб хотя бы знать куда копать.

Comment: @Hidiyoshi а в итоговом jar'нике эта библиотека есть внутри?

Comment: Нету, вообще ни одной библиотеки, только классы, манифест и прочие файлы от мавена

Comment: @Hidiyoshi а на классы из `com.google.code.gson` так же ругается? Если да, то проблема не в `javax.servlet-api`, а в самой сборке.

Comment: при запуске jar файла только на сервелеты ругается

Comment: @Hidiyoshi потому что это первая ошибка. Попробуйте перед строкой, где выдаётся ошибка, добавить вызов какого-то класса из `com.google.code.gson`, чтоб убедиться, что проблема в сборщике в целом.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, проблема была в сборке файла. Поменял содержимое тега <buld>

Comment: @Hidiyoshi как и предполагал. Хорошо, что всё решилось)